# Scroll bar of iOS web view change into half of it should be

Tags: webview, ios7, scrollbar

Using Xcode 5, iOS 7.

Problems occurs after changing the frame of the web view from (0, 45, 320, 568 - 20 - 45 - 49) to (0, 0, 320, 568 - 20) or change it back, its superview is its container with a frame (0, 20, 320, 548) to the rootViewController of application window.

When changing web view's frame back to (0, 45, 320, 568 - 20 - 45 - 49) to its container, web view is within 65 to (568 - 49) vertical area, but its scroll bar is scrolling from 65 to around middle of the web view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A Solution

Finally I worked it around by give this:

```
[[[_webViewContainer webView] scrollView] setScrollIndicatorInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
```

whenever a new web page gets loaded in web view, that is, the very beginning of this UIWebViewDelegate protocol method

```
-(BOOL)webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType
```

So even if the auto layout is turned on, we can force the scroll view (the property of web view) give have correct scrolling range for the scroll indicator.

### Possible Cause

The reason of the unexpected behavior can be seen by:

```
UIEdgeInsets tempEdgeInsets;
tempEdgeInsets = [[_webView scrollView] scrollIndicatorInsets];
NSLog(@"scroll view edge insets = %f, %f, %f, %f", tempEdgeInsets.top, tempEdgeInsets.bottom, tempEdgeInsets.left, tempEdgeInsets.right);
```

Every time the change of web view frame would give a `tempEdgeInsets.bottom` to `520` because of the auto layout I guess.