# Fail to add constraints

Tags: ios7, constraints, autolayout

In iOS 7, trying to add some constraints to make sure a web view is in this position of its superview (that is the web view container in the following code) after changing the frame of the web view. Also I want to make sure that the scroll view within the web view match the same bounds as the web view, so that I can have a correct vertical scrolling indicator. The web view container's frame with regard to its superview (the view of root view controller of application window) is, in pseudo code `(origin.x = 0, origin.y = 20, size.width = 320, size.height = 568 - 20 = 548)`.

The code is written by me to add the above constraints.

The error messages I received when running my code. Don't understand why I can't add new constraints to replace the old ones. The problem is I didn't create old constraints myself, it's automatically generated somewhere I don't know. Don't understand the error messages too, like what does this mean "`NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xc17e930 h=--& v=--& UIWebView:0xc06b020.midY == + 274`".

### Code

```
[[_webViewContainer webView] addConstraint:
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:[[_webViewContainer webView] scrollView]
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                              relatedBy:0
                                 toItem:[_webViewContainer webView]
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                             multiplier:1
                               constant:0]];
[[_webViewContainer webView] addConstraint:
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:[[_webViewContainer webView] scrollView]
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                              relatedBy:0
                                 toItem:[_webViewContainer webView]
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                             multiplier:1
                               constant:0]];
[[_webViewContainer webView] addConstraint:
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:[[_webViewContainer webView] scrollView]
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                              relatedBy:0
                                 toItem:[_webViewContainer webView]
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                             multiplier:1
                               constant:0]];
[[_webViewContainer webView] addConstraint:
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:[[_webViewContainer webView] scrollView]
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                              relatedBy:0
                                 toItem:[_webViewContainer webView]
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                             multiplier:1
                               constant:0]];
[[_webViewContainer webView] setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
[[_webViewContainer webView] layoutSubviews];

[_webViewContainer addConstraint:
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:[_webViewContainer webView]
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                              relatedBy:0
                                 toItem:_webViewContainer
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                             multiplier:1
                               constant:45]];
[_webViewContainer addConstraint:
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:[_webViewContainer webView]
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                              relatedBy:0
                                 toItem:_webViewContainer
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                             multiplier:1
                               constant:-49]];
[_webViewContainer addConstraint:
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:[_webViewContainer webView]
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                              relatedBy:0
                                 toItem:_webViewContainer
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                             multiplier:1
                               constant:0]];
[_webViewContainer addConstraint:
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:[_webViewContainer webView]
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                              relatedBy:0
                                 toItem:_webViewContainer
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                             multiplier:1
                               constant:0]];
[_webViewContainer setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
[_webViewContainer layoutSubviews];
```

### Error Messages

```
2013-11-05 21:32:03.422 emptyproject[16471:70b] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xc17e930 h=--& v=--& UIWebView:0xc06b020.midY == + 274>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xc17e960 h=--& v=--& V:[UIWebView:0xc06b020(454)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xc1803f0 V:|-(45)-[UIWebView:0xc06b020]   (Names: '|':UIViewWebViewContainer:0xbfb76d0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0xc1803f0 V:|-(45)-[UIWebView:0xc06b020]   (Names: '|':UIViewWebViewContainer:0xbfb76d0 )>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2013-11-05 21:32:03.423 emptyproject[16471:70b] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xc17e930 h=--& v=--& UIWebView:0xc06b020.midY == + 274>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xc17e960 h=--& v=--& V:[UIWebView:0xc06b020(454)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xc17ed80 h=--& v=--& V:[UIViewWebViewContainer:0xbfb76d0(548)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xc1802b0 UIWebView:0xc06b020.bottom == UIViewWebViewContainer:0xbfb76d0.bottom - 49>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0xc1802b0 UIWebView:0xc06b020.bottom == UIViewWebViewContainer:0xbfb76d0.bottom - 49>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2013-11-05 21:32:03.424 emptyproject[16471:70b] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xc17e930 h=--& v=--& UIWebView:0xc06b020.midY == + 274>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xc17e960 h=--& v=--& V:[UIWebView:0xc06b020(548)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xc1803f0 V:|-(45)-[UIWebView:0xc06b020]   (Names: '|':UIViewWebViewContainer:0xbfb76d0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0xc1803f0 V:|-(45)-[UIWebView:0xc06b020]   (Names: '|':UIViewWebViewContainer:0xbfb76d0 )>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2013-11-05 21:32:16.334 emptyproject[16471:70b] web view container (Drawer.m handleLogoutScheme line 938) origin x = 0.000000, origin y = 20.000000, width = 320.000000, height = 548.000000 in the coordinate system of web view container's superview
2013-11-05 21:32:16.336 emptyproject[16471:4707] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
2013-11-05 21:32:24.822 emptyproject[16471:70b] web view container (Drawer.m handleLoginScheme line 860) origin x = 0.000000, origin y = 20.000000, width = 320.000000, height = 548.000000 in the coordinate system of web view container's superview
2013-11-05 21:32:24.823 emptyproject[16471:70b] [[_webViewContainer webView] constraints] = (
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xc168600 V:|-(0)-[_UIWebViewScrollView:0xbfb8220]   (Names: '|':UIWebView:0xc06b020 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xc17d780 _UIWebViewScrollView:0xbfb8220.bottom == UIWebView:0xc06b020.bottom>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xc17db20 H:|-(0)-[_UIWebViewScrollView:0xbfb8220](LTR)   (Names: '|':UIWebView:0xc06b020 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xc17dce0 _UIWebViewScrollView:0xbfb8220.right == UIWebView:0xc06b020.right>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xc17dfa0 h=--& v=-&- _UIWebViewScrollView:0xbfb8220.midX == + 160>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xc17e0c0 h=--& v=-&- H:[_UIWebViewScrollView:0xbfb8220(320)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xc17e0f0 h=--& v=-&- _UIWebViewScrollView:0xbfb8220.midY == UIWebView:0xc06b020.midY>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xc17e220 h=--& v=-&- _UIWebViewScrollView:0xbfb8220.height == UIWebView:0xc06b020.height>"
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default view that was created programmatically has translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to YES. It means that the autoresizing mask on a view gives rise to constraints that fully determine the view's position.  Any constraints you set on the view are likely to conflict with autoresizing constraints, so you must turn off this property first. IB will turn it off for you.

So set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to NO before adding new constraints:

```
[[[_webViewContainer webView] scrollView] setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```

Comment: Hi @MarkKryzhanouski, your method works! But I can't change the constraint for a second time, only first time work...

Comment: Why do you need to add constraints twice?

Comment: Hi @MarkKryzhanouski, I need to change the web view between two sizes frequently, one size to accommodate navigation bar and tab bar, the other full screen except the status bar.

Comment: Once you added constraints you may save them in properties for further modification. For example if you need to modify webView top spacing just do following: `self.webViewTopConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: _webViewContainer webView] attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:0 toItem:_webViewContainer attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1constant:45]; [_webViewContainer addConstraint:self.webViewTopConstraint];` and then when you need to just update constant value of this constraint: `self.webViewTopConstraint.constant = 145;`

Comment: To @MarkKryzhanouski, Finally I find a work-around for my wrestling with auto layout: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19785071/scroll-bar-of-ios-web-view-change-into-half-of-it-should-be/19793515#19793515